# Intellij VIM mode, jump-list (CTRL-O) not recording navigation

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to jump to the definition of the word under the cursor, and I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to jump back to where I came from. But if I do something like control-click on something, that jump list does not seem to record where I came from. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then will not jump back to where I was when I control-clicked.

Is there a way to make sure that the jump list will not miss this?

Comment: After `<C-]>`, you can use `<C-t>` to jump back.

Comment: That works. Is there an opposite of C-t as well?

Answer (score 5):

## TAG NAVIGATION

The [tag stack](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tag-stack) stores all tags used to jump to/from.

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> is used to follow the tag under the cursor.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> is used to jump to the previous entry in the tag stack.
- `:tag` is used to jump to the next entry in the tag stack.

## JUMP NAVIGATION

The [jump list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#jump-motions) stores all positions the cursor jumped to/from. According to Vim's documentation, motion is considered a "jump" in the following conditions:

```
A "jump" is one of the following commands: "'"', "`", "G", "/", "?", "n",
"N", "%", "(", ")", "[[", "]]", "{", "}", ":s", ":tag", "L", "M", "H" and
the commands that start editing a new file.
```

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> is used to move cursor do older entry in jump list.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> is used to move mursor to newer entry in jump list.

## REFERENCES

[`:help tag-commands`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tag-commands):

```
g<LeftMouse>                        *g<LeftMouse>*
<C-LeftMouse>                   *<C-LeftMouse>* *CTRL-]*
CTRL-]          Jump to the definition of the keyword under the
            cursor.  Same as ":tag {ident}", where {ident} is the
            keyword under or after cursor.
            When there are several matching tags for {ident}, jump
            to the [count] one.  When no [count] is given the
            first one is jumped to. See |tag-matchlist| for
            jumping to other matching tags.
            {Vi: identifier after the cursor}
```

[`:help tag-stack`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tag-stack):

```
g<RightMouse>                       *g<RightMouse>*
<C-RightMouse>                  *<C-RightMouse>* *CTRL-T*
CTRL-T          Jump to [count] older entry in the tag stack
            (default 1).  {not in Vi}

                        *:po* *:pop* *E555* *E556*
:[count]po[p][!]    Jump to [count] older entry in tag stack (default 1).
            See |tag-!| for [!].  {not in Vi}

:[count]ta[g][!]    Jump to [count] newer entry in tag stack (default 1).
            See |tag-!| for [!].  {not in Vi}
```

[`:help jump-motions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#jump-motions):

```
                            *CTRL-O*
CTRL-O          Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list
            (not a motion command).  {not in Vi}
            {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}


<Tab>       or                  *CTRL-I* *<Tab>*
CTRL-I          Go to [count] newer cursor position in jump list
            (not a motion command).
            In a |quickfix-window| it takes you to the position of
            the error under the cursor.
            {not in Vi}
            {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}
```

Comment: It seems that ctrl-] records the current position in the jump list. Both ctrl-t and ctrl-o takes you back. It seems that the odd thing is that a control-mouse click does not record it in the jump list.
Question then remains is if ctrl-o takes you back, what's the point of ctrl-t?

Comment: `ctrl-o` controls the jump list. I'll try to expand this answer later, but for now try searching for a keyword after following a tag and only then pressing `ctrl-o`.

Comment: It seems that any "jump" that IdeaVim does, is recorded in the jump list, but any "jump" that the IDE makes, is not recorded in the jump list.
For instance, ctrl-] you can return from using ctrl-o.
But using F4 can not be returned from using ctrl-o.

So the question is, how can we avoid the jump list from missing jumps that the IDE makes?

Comment: do we have a solution now?

Comment: It doesn't look like `:tag`, `:tagselect` and other colon commands for tag stack are supported.